# How can I view all machine level environment variables using a single PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I can use this to get all of the user environment variables:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\
```

and this to get a single environment variable:

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH','machine')
```

but what command can I use to view all machine level environment variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `System.Environment` class has another static method `GetEnvironmentVariables()` (note the trailing "s"). You can call it without argument to get all environment variables (similar to `Get-ChildItem env:`), or with the same arguments as the second parameter of the `GetEnvironmentVariable()` method to get the variables for a particular target (e.g. machine, user, or process).

This will do what you want:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables('machine')
```